# Why do { } while(condition); needs semicolon at the end of it but while(condition) {} doesn't?

Tags: c++, c, while-loop, do-while

I always have problem with placing `;` at the end of `while` or not placing it at the end of `do while` loops. So what's the reason? Why

```
int numItemsToProcess = 3;  
while(numItemsToProcess > 0)  
{  
    // process an item  
    numItemsToProcess--;  
}
```

doesn't need `;` at the end but

```
do  
{  
    numItemsToProcess --;
} while (numItemsToProcess > 0);
```

does?
Maybe the reason is not too important. but when you know the reason you can remember where to put `;`.

Comment: Because the syntax of C or C++ is so defined.

Comment: There is one case when you need to place `;` after `}` - it's class/struct/union declaration. In other hand, you **must** place `;` after each statement

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: That's not an answer.  Joachim Pileborg posted the answer.  Yours is just noise and discourages curiosity.  "Because the spec says so herp derp" answers suck.  Obviously there is a *reason* for each rule.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch ~> But I think it wasn't randomly chosen :)

Comment: @EdS. Sadly, the C and C++ standards are far for rational. There isn't necessarily a logical explanation why the standard adopted a certain syntax. Or maybe there once was one, but you would have to do programming language archaeology and find the rationale for the BCPL language or similar.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You put semicolon after all statements, except the block statement. This is the reason that you place it after the `while` in `do while`, but not after the block in the `while {...}`.

You also use it to terminate almost all declarations. The only exceptions I can think about at the moment is function bodies, and `namespace` bodies in C++.

Answer (score 12):

They are two different loop constructs.  You just need to remember.

Think of them as one-liners:

```
do one_thing while( condition );

do { stuff } while( condition );
```

and

```
while( condition ) one_thing;

while( condition ) { stuff }
```

These are all expressions that require a semi-colon at the end, except the last one, where the braces logically denotes the end of the expression (think of `if` statements).

Comment: Or `do stuff while(condition);`

Comment: Oh, thanks =)  To be honest I've never used that construct.  I'd better update.

Comment: Yep.  The "stuff" only needs to be a statement.  It doesn't necessarily need to be a compound statement (also called a "block").

Answer (score 0):

Because It's a standard.
Refer [The ISO C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf)   Page Number 128
Also
It's because while statements are valid within a do-while loop.

```
int x = 10;
int y = 10;

do 
 while(x > 0)
  x--;
 while(x = y--);
```

Because you're ending the statement.
A statement ends either with a block (delimited by curly braces),
or with a semicolon. "do this while this" is a single statement, and can't end with a block (because it ends with the "while"),
so it needs a semicolon just like any other statement.

Comment: The other answers explain the logic behind the standard.  Perhaps you could provide your take on it too?

Comment: That is not "The ISO C++ Standard."  That is the _Final Committee Draft_ of the C++11 Standard.  There are many differences between that draft and the final C++11 Standard document.  The closest publicly available draft to the final document is [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), I believe.

Comment: I think its [N3485](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is as follows

1. **While condition**:- While condition have the signature like

   ```
   while (expression) 
      statement
   ```

While loop executes according to the expression provided to it. If the expression is true then the statement written in while {} will execute else not. You can also mark `;` after `while (expression);` but it will merely complete the `while` syntax immediately, as `;` indicates end of statement. In general `whil`e loop checks expression and executes list of statements inside.

2. **Do While condition**:- Do while have a signature like

   ```
   do
       statement
   while (expression);
   ```

`do-while` is an interesting loop. It have specialty that the statements following `do` will execute atleast ones no matter whether `expression` in `while` is true or false. The flow of `do while` says that the statement following `do` will execute once and then the `while` condition is checked. If `while` condition is true, again statements following `do` will be executed. The reason why there is `;` at the end of `do ... while (expression);` is because here `while` is treated as a statement as because its body is above it. In c++ every statement must end with **;** so `do while` ends with `;`.

Comment: '`while` is treated as a statement' is not correct. The entire `do ... while ()` is a statement.